# Scan wifi APs without turn on Wifi? [Android]

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

<strike>Is it possible to scan wifi APs without turn on Wifi?</strike> I built an App that scan for wifi APs.. If wifi is disabled the app turn wifi on and off to scan. But I noticed a problem, when I was using my Smartphone as an Access Point and when the app turned on wifi my smartphone stopped being an Access Point.

If this is not possible and if there is no other way to do this I've to accept this "problem"..

**Curiosity:** <strike>Is it possible to turn on and off wifi without being "visible" for the user?</strike>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though in latest Android version (*KitKat*) there is an option for *Scan-Only* mode, it is impossible to obtain scan results with disabled WiFi. There is no way to make this totally hidden from user perspective. Howewer, with *Scan-Only* mode getting the scan results is basically an instant operation (since they are already available), so it would be hardly noticeable. Please note, this mode can be disabled.

So, on your place I would just do the same thing: turn WiFi on, get scan results, turn WiFi off. Safe, convenient, compatible.

As to the use case with AP (so called *SoftAP*) and WiFi (so called *Station*) at the same time - while working as WiFi engineer for one of the major Android phone OEM's, I'm not aware of any Android WiFi solution that is capable of running both *SoftAP* and *Station* at the same time. This is mostly due to technical limitations and power consumption of mobile phones.

Comment: Well, 6 years after I wrote this I finally saw a WiFi solution from Qualcomm that is capable of having AP and STA modes at the same time. Not sure what the actual chip is, but here's the driver name and version: `qca_cld3_wlan.ko`, `v5.1.1.50R`.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning Wifi Access Points without your wifi being on is like taking picture without running your camera app or not removing your camera lens cap! :)

`Is it possible to turn on and off wifi without being "visible" for the user?`
What do you means by `being visible`. If your wifi is configured to acts as a AP, you should create a hidden AP, if not, you're not AP and you're not visible.

I'm just guessing a solution that might works, When your app turned on wifi, just wait till your wifi start as a AP and then try scanning.

Comment: Ok.. It was a confusing question.. Of course that wifi has to be active to scan wifi AP.. My question should be more like: is possible enable wifi just for one App so as not to influence other applications?

You didn't understand the "Access Point" part.. In mine LG 4x, the Access Point mode just works if wifi is disabled....

What I mean when I say "without being visible for user" is doesn't show wifi symbol in settings bar when its state is changed.

Comment: Ahaa! As much as I know this is not possible(99%) but if you find any solution for this, please let me know that :)

Answer (score 0):

to on wifi

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

to off Wifi

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks .. but that doesn't answer to my question :)

Comment: Is it possible to turn on and off wifi without being "visible" for the user.above code do the same thing